# C# How can I refactor code to use interface reflection

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, lambda, interface

I have a list where I have been adding validation classes which inherit `IValidation` interface, but now I would like to use reflection  go explicitly through all classes that inherit `ISpecialCaseRequestValidation` interface.

Here is my Validation class:

```
private static List<IValidation> _validations = new List<IValidation>();

static Validations()
{
}

public static bool IsValid(SpecialCaseRequest specialCase, out HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var result = _validations.FirstOrDefault(v => !v.IsValid(SpecialCase, out error));
    if (result != null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now I have a error on `!v.IsValid` , because I already moved `IsValid` from `IValidation` to `ISpecialCaseRequestValidation` interface. Here are my interfaces:

```
public interface ISpecialCaseRequestValidation: IValidation
{
    bool IsValid(SpecialCaseRequest specialCase, out Error error);
}
public interface IValidation
{
}
```

And here are my classes which inherit `ISpecialCaseRequestValidation` interface:

```
public class NameValidation : ISpecialCaseRequestValidation
{
    public bool IsValid(SpecialCaseRequest specialCase, out Error error)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }
}

public class ExpirationDateTimeValidation : ISpecialCaseRequestValidation{}

public class AgeValidation : ISpecialCaseRequestValidation{}
```

How can I define with reflection these interfaces and it will go through all classes which inherit `ISpecialCaseRequestValidation` interface and lambda expression to pick IsValid method?

UPDATE:

Well, I have got all classes assemblies and I see them name:

```
Assembly a = typeof(ISpecialCaseRequestValidation).Assembly;
var list = a.GetTypes().Where(type => type != typeof(ISpecialCaseRequestValidation) && typeof(ISpecialCaseRequestValidation).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
```

But problem is that when I am using `var list` I can't access to classes `IsValid` method, I can see only classes attributes.

Comment: Please take more time to indent your code properly in future. It's really important that your question is as easy to read and understand as possible.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what exactly you're asking and why you think you need reflection for that. Aren't you simply looking for `validation as ISpecialCaseRequestValidation`?

Comment: @CodeCaster well I need reflection for future cases, because maybe in a future IValidation interface could be adapted not only for ISpecialCaseRequestValidion , but for other as well

Comment: It's still unclear _what exactly_ you want to do. Do you want to find all classes implementing an interface? Do you want to check if an instance of a certain type implements an interface? What are you going to do with the interface? Reflection operates at runtime on symbols defined at compile-time. You can't apply an interface at runtime, if that is what you want.

Comment: @CodeCaster Name parameter cannot be empty or null string// Yes , I want to found all classes which are implemented by ISpecialCaseRequestValidation interface and that will avoid to me to do _validations.Add(new NameValidation()) and instead of that I can have relection which could detect what classes I am using. IValidation interface is stand for global, it can inherit also another interfaces, but it is for future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in this way:

```
static Validations()
{
Assembly a = typeof(ISpecialCaseRequestValidation).Assembly;
            _validationTypes =
                a.GetTypes()
                    .Where(
                        type =>
                            type != typeof(ISpecialCaseRequestValidation) &&
                            typeof(ISpecialCaseRequestValidation).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                    .ToList();
}
```

Here I am getting Assembly of Interface class and put it to the list.

```
public static bool IsValid(SpecialCaseRequest specialCase, out HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    object[] mParam = new object[] { signingCase, new Error() };
        foreach (Type type in _validationTypes)
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var isValidMethod = type.GetMethod("IsValid");
            var isValid = (bool) isValidMethod.Invoke(obj, mParam);
        }
    if (result != null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And with object[] I pass through all IsValid() method which I invoked in isValid variable.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I see it your interface declarations should be changed to be:

```
public interface ISpecialCaseRequestValidation: IValidation
{
}
public interface IValidation
{
    bool IsValid(SpecialCaseRequest specialCase, out Error error);
}
```

All classes which inherit from `ISpecialCaseRequestValidation` will have to implement `IsValid` and so will all classes which inherit from `IValidation`. I suggest this because I assume that also children from `IValidation` should be checked for validity.

I'd like to add that you could write

```
public static bool IsValid(SpecialCaseRequest specialCase, out HttpResponseMessage response) =>
    _validations.All(v => v.IsValid(specialCase, out error));
```

instead of

```
public static bool IsValid(SpecialCaseRequest specialCase, out HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var result = _validations.FirstOrDefault(v => !v.IsValid(SpecialCase, out error));
    if (result != null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```